# Gtest linking error (moved from GCC 4.x to GCC 7.x)

Tags: c++, gcc, googletest, waf

I am using Waf as a build tool to build a C++ library.
I had earlier been using GCC 4.8.x and using std=c++98, and it was working fine

However, when I tried to change the compiler version to GCC 7.2, there were a host of issues all related to Gtest. 
Ex : undefined reference to `testing::internal::PrintStringTo

I would be grateful if someone could kindly share some information on how to eliminate this issue, while retaining the unit tests written through Gtest

regards,
Tej

Comment: Are you still trying to use the same gtest library binary, or did you rebuild the library using gcc 7.2?

Comment: Hi aschepler,
I did not rebuild the binary, which is probably why it is causing a mismatch when trying to link.

Can you kindly let me know how I can install gtest source and build it with GCC 7.x ?

-Tej

Comment: what gtest version you are using? Latest or some earlier? What C++ standard - c++98, C++11, C++14 or C++17 (latest)  or just default for gcc7.2 (C++14 I guess)?

Comment: having same issue. Have you found any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

gtest is depended from used compiler, so, take a gtest source code 
    wget https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.tar.gz
and install it using your compiler as a default compiler